# Создание узора через цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Xочю научиться вышивать крестиком и сделать орнаменты на вышивки. 
Появилась идея написать программу, которая будет делать орнамент нужной ширины и длины,
которые можно будет использовать в качестве примера для вышивки.

Вышивка – это прямоугольник `m×n`. 
Орнаменты — это два луча, выходящих из верхних углов вышивки
и имеющих углы `45` градусов. 
Луч отражается, когда прикасается к вертикальному краю.
Когда луч прикасается к нижнему краю, он исчезает.

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать такую программу,
которая согласно заданной ширине n и длине m выведет пример орнамента.

Входные данные Первая строка содержит два целых числа `m` и `n` (3≤n,m≤1000) - высота и ширина соответственно.

Выходные данные Выведите орнамент размерами `n×m`.

---

Для лучшего понимания вы можете посмотреть примеры.

Входные данные: `6 4`

Входные данные:

```
x..x
.xx.
.xx.
x..x
.xx.
.xx.
```

Входные данные: `12 5`

Входные данные:

```
x...x
.x.x.
..x..
.x.x.
x...x
.x.x.
..x..
.x.x.
x...x
.x.x.
..x..
.x.x.
```

Входные данные: `21 12`

Входные данные:

```
x..........x
.x........x.
..x......x..
...x....x...
....x..x....
.....xx.....
.....xx.....
....x..x....
...x....x...
..x......x..
.x........x.
x..........x
.x........x.
..x......x..
...x....x...
....x..x....
.....xx.....
.....xx.....
....x..x....
...x....x...
..x......x..
```

---

**main.py**:

```py
m,n = map (int, input(). split())

vishivanka = []

for x in range(m):
    vishivanka.append([])
    for y in range(n):
        vishivanka[x].append(".")

for x in range(m):
    print()
    for y in range(n):
        if x==y:
            vishivanka[x][y] = "x"

for y in range(n):
    vishivanka[y][n-y-1] = "x"

for x in range(m):
    print()
    for y in range(n):
        print(vishivanka[x][y], end=" ")
```

Написанный код не работает как надо, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: У нас принято задавать вопросы только на русском языке. Вы можете изменить вопрос нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Суть вопроса должна быть приведена на русском языке. А по решению - подумайте, как позиции крестиков зависят от чётности `x//ширина` и от остатка от деления этих величин

Comment: @SergeyMikhalkov А к chatGPT с подобными вопросами лезть не советую. В программировании он ничего не понимает и про ошибки в коде умеет только говорить чушь с умным видом.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
flag = True
while flag:
    m, n = map(int, input('\nВведите количество строк и столбцов \n'\
        'например: 6 4 или 0 0 для выхода: ').split())
    if not m:
        break
    vishivanka = []

    print(f'\nстрок={m}; столбцов={n}') #

    for x in range(m):
        vishivanka.append([])
        for y in range(n):
            vishivanka[x].append(".")

    for x in range(m):
        if not (x % (n-1)):                        
            _y = -1
            _x = 0

        vishivanka[x][_x] = "x"
        vishivanka[x][_y] = "x"                 
                
        _y -= 1
        _x += 1

    for x in range(m):
        print()
        for y in range(n):
            print(vishivanka[x][y], end=" ")           
    print()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]